# How to run SSIS Package through .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, ssis

Is it Possible to run the SSIS package in Asp .net MVC3 using c# coding?For example i'm having a SSIS package to delete data from particular table and import that table with new data from excel sheet every month. is it possible to do it on a button click event of asp .net web application?

Answer (score 2):

You need SSIS on the same server as your asp.net application. Then you can use the SSIS .net api:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/call-ssis-2012-package-within-net.html and 
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/01/call-ssis-2012-package-within-net.html
[image]

An other trick could be to start a job via TSQL/.Net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx

Or create a webservice on the machine that runs SSIS and then call that webservice via your asp.net application...